# Map and Convert to Array of String, ""Cannot convert return expression of type '[NumbersResponse.numbers]' to return type 'Array<String>' "

Tags: arrays, swift

I've got a model that resembles the response from the back end, which looks something like this

```
public enum Numbers: String, Codable {
    case one = "one"
    case two = "two"
    case three = "three"
}

public init(numbers: [Numbers]) {
    self.numbers = Numbers
}
```

I'm trying to extract Numbers and convert it to an array of string like this

```
public var numbers: Array<String> {
    return NumbersResponse.numbers

}
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type '[NumbersResponse.numbers]'
> to return type 'Array'

I've tried using a map as well but no luck.*

Comment: Can you show us the `numbers` variable?

Comment: `return NumbersResponse.numbers.map{ $0.rawValue }`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this code:

```
public var numbers: Array<String> {
    return NumbersResponse.numbers
}
```

You are trying to assign an array of type Numbers to an array of strings.

It's hard to answer without more context, but I guess you have two options to solve it. First, your ***numbers*** variables defined as an array of ***Numbers***

```
public var numbers: [Numbers] {
    return NumbersResponse.numbers
}
```

Or as an array of Strings:

```
public var numbers: [String] {
    return NumbersResponse.numbers.map { $0.rawValue }
}
```